# Centering Left Justified List Items

Tags: html, css

I have collection of list items that I would like to be left justified when wrapping but centered within a list similar the way iOS icons appear on the home screen.

My problem is that, at certain screen sizes, the elements will automatically wrap to a new line, but unwanted padding will remain on the right hand side.

[image]

I know that I can center the list inside a parent container, but that still won't center the list items since the list itself is creating that extra padding.

My styling is as follows:

```
li {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-indent: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This fiddle demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Ea8Kd/1/

How can I remove the unwanted padding, or center the items inside the list while ensuring the second line is left justified?

Comment: I don't think this can be done the way you're describing without the use of JS.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy I think you may be right. Mostly I was posting this question in hopes that I was wrong.

Comment: If you wrap the `ul` in a container and place the green bg on that container, you can center the `ul`. Is that an option?

Comment: @ralph.m Unfortunately, even if I center the list inside a parent container, the list items inside will still appear off-center. This is due to the fact that the list is taking up the additional space on the right hand side, which I can't seem to remove.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. There are sort of solutions for that, like setting the boxes to `display: inline-block` and justifying them, but you need [a few extra hacks](http://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/GECBF) to get everything looking right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you wanted but I added

```
ul {
   max-width: 550px;
   }
```

Removed padding on the right side.

If this isn't it could you show a picture of what you wanted? You're question isn't 100% clear.

Comment: Originally, I was hoping that there would be a solution that would allow the list to adjust to the screen size so that there could be a variable number of icons per line. However, setting a max width effectively capping the number of items that can appear per line seems the only way to get this working.